# Most related word in meaning

Tags: synonyms

What is the word that means to relate one as an expert to have a stronghold of a specific field or knowledge

Comment: Single word requests require a sample sentence in which the word will be used. Please see the Tour.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [expression or idiom for a person who knows every detail about something](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/277332/expression-or-idiom-for-a-person-who-knows-every-detail-about-something)

Answer (score 0):

**A subject-matter expert** (SME) or **domain expert** is a person who is an authority in a particular area or topic.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject-matter_expert

Or, simply, **Expert**, "a person who is very knowledgeable about or skilful in a particular area."

Answer (score 0):

(awaiting OP's sample sentence for my final edit)

a **professional**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/professional)

> Of, relating to, engaged in, or suitable for a profession b.
>   Conforming to the standards of a profession: professional behavior.
>   2. Engaging in a given activity as a source of livelihood or as a career
>   3. Performed by persons receiving pay
>   4. Having or showing great skill; expert:

Answer (score 0):

specialist

> 1.A person who concentrates primarily on a particular subject or activity; a person highly skilled in a specific and restricted
>   field.
>  ‘he is a specialist in psychometric testing’
>  [Oxford
>   Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/specialist)

A dermatologist knows more about skin than a general practitioner.
A botanist knows more about plants than a biologist/naturalist.

These guys are specialists.